# How do Ethereum clients generate unique addresses?

Tags: addresses, clients, light-clients, ethereum-wallet-dapp

How do Ethereum clients, like Ethereum Wallet or Eth-Lightwallet, generate unique addresses that haven't been used before, and what is the likelihood that these addresses have been used?

Comment: Related: http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/4299/account-uniqueness-guaranteed

Answer (score 13):

The address is derived from a random private key. The client does not check if it has been previously used because the chance of that happening is nearly zero.

Comment: Well lets not forget the golden rule of Murphy law - what can happen - will happen or as he said "whatever can go wrong, will go wrong."

Answer (score 11):

I think the most important phrase in your question is 'what is the likelihood'.

The other answers are correct in determining that there is a 1 in 2^160 likelihood of finding a collision *with 100% probability*.

Due to the [birthday paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem), cryptographers give a hash function with output bitlength 160 a bitwise security rating of 80. This is because with 2^80 addresses, it is **more likely than not** (i.e the probability is over 50%) **that you will have an address collision**.

For visual comparison with the above answers, the birthday problem implies a collision will occur with probability 1 in 1,208,925,819,614,629,174,706,176, yikes.

Comment: What the birthday problem says is that if you generate addresses using 2^80 random seeds, the chance of some pair of generated addresses being the same is ~50%. That's different than saying that if you generate a new address the chance that it will have been used before is 1 in 2^80. The correct probability is 1 in 2^160 times the number of addresses that have already been generated.

Comment: Ah yeah I get the distinction, I guess interpreted the question as more 'when are we likely to get an address collision' and less 'what is the likelihood that each new address generation (starting from 0 addresses) will result in a collision'.

Answer (score 3):

Ethereum Wallet (the official wallet that will use Mist) uses `web3.personal.newAccount` to create an account. This is a web3.js call that does the equivalent of `geth account new`.

The address space in Ethereum is a 20-byte value (160-bit address space, same as Bitcoin).

> what is the likelihood that these addresses have been used?

2^160 or about **1 in 1,461,501,637,330,902,918,203,684,832,716,283,019,655,932,542,976**

Comment: When the account is created, is there a check to see if any other transactions have used this address previously?

Comment: @paulmorriss I couldn't find one, but it's possible I just missed something.

Comment: Nope, if you create an account that points to an existing wallet then you can spend all the ETH that's in there

Answer (score 3):

Ethereum uses addresses that are 160 bits long. The chance that any one address is the same as any other given address is therefore 1 in 2^160. However, due to the [birthday paradox](https://betterexplained.com/articles/understanding-the-birthday-paradox/) the chance that a new Ethereum address is the same as any already existing Ethereum address rises exponentially with every new Ethereum address and is calculated as following:

Number of possible pairs: ([number of unique Ethereum addresses](https://etherscan.io/chart/address) + 1 / number of unique Ethereum addresses) = ((4,807,984 + 1) * 4,807,984) / 2 = [11,558,357,476,120](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=((4,807,984%20%2B%201)%20*%204,807,984)%20%2F%202)

Chance of a unique pair: ((2^160)-1) / 2^160) = [0.999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999315772234](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=((2%5E160)-1)%20%2F%202%5E160))

Chance of 11,558,357,476,120 unique pairs = 0.999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999315772234 ^ 11,558,357,476,120 = [0.999999999999999999999999999999999992091451](https://sandbox.open.wolframcloud.com/app/objects/3a5d67ed-4143-42df-818c-a35c2e10f322#sidebar=compute)

Chance of some match = 1 - 0.999999999999999999999999999999999992091451 = [7.908549 × 10^-36](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1%20-%200.999999999999999999999999999999999992091451)

As of today (26 Jul 2017) the chance of a new Ethereum address being the same as an already existing Ethereum address is ~8 × 10^-36