# Is it possible to regenerate the private key file?

Tags: private-key, keystore, password

I have created an account in testnet which I know the address and the password of, but I did not backup the private key file. Can I somehow create the key file again using the password? Or is my account locked inside forever?

Thanks,

Comment: Your password has nothing to do with the creation of private key. However, the public and private key are mathematically related to each other but the strength of a public key cryptosystem lies on an assumption that private keys cannot be regenerated from public keys. So, there's no way to regenerate the private key.

Comment: I figured out how to recover my lost UTC files. But I'm not going to tell you because apparently I'm too stupid.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot recreate the private key file. The password is used to decrypt the key file, and then an address is generated from the private key in a non-reversible way. The private key is really the most important piece and should be [backed up](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/108/how-do-i-backup-my-ether-accounts).

Comment: @jeff: Geth works this way because the private key needs to be as random as possible ([example](http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/4299/account-uniqueness-guaranteed)) and humans are [notoriously bad at entropy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Password_strength#Human-generated_passwords), and I loathe to mention it but a brainwallet is the term for a private key derived from a password fyi.