# Is an Ethereum address with no outgoing transactions initialized if someone sends funds into it?

Tags: wallets

If there exists an address that nobody (yet) owns the private key to, and somebody sends funds into it, does that private key get initialized to nobody, and no one will ever be able to access it?

I am asking for something like REXmls, [who sent their ICO funds to an address that doesn't exist](https://www.reddit.com/r/ethtrader/comments/6qryc2/did_rexmls_ico_just_lost_6600_eth_due_to_a/). Will somebody, some day generate a wallet with that public key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Theoretically, if someone happen to generate an account address of the same (to own the private key of the address), even it's an already owned account, he gets the chance to use that account.

But the probability of that happening is nearly rare due to the immense no of possible values (2**160 -> likelihood of 1 in 1,208,925,819,614,629,174,706,176).

You may refer [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/10055/is-each-ethereum-address-shared-by-theoretically-2-96-private-keys) for some mathematical explanation and guaranteeing of uniqueness [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/4299/account-uniqueness-guaranteed/4301#4301) .