# Unique Private key will never have a duplicate?

Tags: go-ethereum, ether

Couldn't you write a script that generates eth accounts continuously and polls to see the balance of each account(hoping that it lands on one with a balance already). What are the logistics on this?

Comment: Related: LBC - Large Bitcoin Collider (https://lbc.cryptoguru.org/about)

Comment: @RichardHorrocks Wow, that's remarkably useful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such a "script" already exists, see "[All Ethereum Private Keys](http://www.ethersecret.com)" or "[Ethereum Private Key Database](https://ethdir.io)". Regarding "logistics", check out the above two sites' FAQ pages to see why there is no need.

Also, see [this question](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/4299/20451)'s answers for estimated cost of the "script".