# Send transactions from any address (account) to a private ethreum network (PoA)

Tags: go-ethereum, transactions, poa, clique

I am trying to send a transaction to a private Ethereum network (PoA) using an arbitrary address. However, the network is not accepting transactions from that address. Are there any method to unlock the network to accept transactions from any address, or I have to unlock each address individually?

Comment: Depending on your node type (e.g., Geth, Parity, etc), there is an API for unlocking an account on the node side, then you can send any transaction with this account without signing it first (the node will sign it for you). However, please note that this is highly discouraged, since anyone who gains access to you node will be able to send transaction at will. Sign the transaction on your end, and send a signed-transaction to the node.

Comment: I want to make my  blockchain public for any one who want to send a transactions, but it is private in the sens that only authorized node can create blocks (mining). In other word, I don't know the address of a transaction sender beforehand. I am using geth (clique)

Comment: So your users will need to sign their transactions. I doubt that any one of them will be willing to unlock their accounts on your private network. Keep in mind that although you call it "private network", the node itself is still accessible via HTTP or HTTPS.

Comment: I didn't get your point? is this mean that if a transaction is signed by the sender itself (using any address), it will be received by the nodes?

Comment: A signed transaction can easily be validated by the node, yes. Unlike what you may think, an address doesn't need to be "registered" in a network. Any correct pair of [public address, private key] is valid on any network. If I understand your confusion correctly, then I had the same confusion myself, and was able to resolve it with [this question](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/63516/16043) (the answers to which you may find useful).

Comment: Thanks, but I am confusing because private network should not need to have prefunded account in order to send a transaction. However, PoA network need it!! and  need to be Unlocked also.