# How do I retrieve funds sent to wrong address that doesn’t exist

Tags: transactions, wallets, addresses, myetherwallet

I sent some funds to my MEW wallet but I fat fingered the address and sent it to a different address that does not seem to exist. How do I claim that address to retrieve funds I see sitting in the block.

Comment: if the transaction is already in the blockchian, it is over and sorry for your lost..

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you cannot claim that address. Those funds are lost forever.

A feature of Ethereum is that there are so many possible addresses that one cannot "choose" an address. This allows for a basically unlimited number of addresses to exist.

You can see more about addresses [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/4299/44893).